# Can't share collections with the team (Cloud licence)

Tags: postman

My team just got Postman Cloud licences. Everything fine, they can share collections/environments, etc, but when I try to do it two messages pop up one after another and the collection isn't shared. I tried with any combination of sharing settings (share with individuals, with whole team, view/edit permissions).

The messages are:
"Collection has been shared"
"There was an error while sharing the collection"

What can I do?

Regards,
Remus